# Minecraft Crashing Before / During Start up (HELP)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've seen a bunch of people saying this but none of the solutions have worked.  I'm running Windows 10, I had Java Runtime 8 (121), uninstalled it over 6 times, rebooted each time and reinstalled. I even went back an update for Java. My game still crashes. It doesn't even pop up the game, it just crashes before it even opens.

Here's the crash log that I get on the new launcher
[image]

And here's the one I get on the older launcher:
[image]

For anyone wondering, my PC runs every other game I own perfectly (including Doom and Alien Isolation) so it doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my computer's capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two important parts of your crash log are:

```
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005cfb6e7e, pid=360, tid=0x00000000000023e4
```

and

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0xfa6e7e]
```

This is [a known issue](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-105853?jql=text%20~%20%22atio6axx%22) (though it's not a bug in Minecraft). The file **atio6axx.dll** is what Minecraft uses to talk to AMD/Radeon brands of video cards, and when it causes an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)` it means that there is a problem with those graphics drivers.

To fix this,

1. Confirm that your graphics drivers [are fully up to date](http://support.amd.com/).
2. If they are fully up to date, this means there is a bug in the latest AMD drivers, and you'll have to wait for AMD to fix them. In that case you might want to [report the bug to AMD](https://community.amd.com/community/support-forums/drivers-software).